# flutter riverpod ConsumerWidget not being rebuilt

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I've just implemented riverpod into a small app I've written.

flutter_riverpod: ^0.12.1

My problem is that when I update a provider the widget isn't being rebuilt despite having made a call to 'watch'.

The provider essentially tracks the current page that should be displayed.

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final currentPageProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => CurrentPage());

class CurrentPage extends StateNotifier<int> {
  CurrentPage() : super(-1);

  set currentPage(int page) {
    log('currentPage set to $page');
    state = page;
  }

  int get currentPage => state;
}
```

The PageButtons widget draws a set of RaisedButtons. When a user clicks one of the raised buttons the current page no. should change and the PageButton widget should be rebuilt so we can change the color of the RaisedButton that corresponds to the current page.

```dart
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:math' hide log;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:fsm2/fsm2.dart' hide State;
import 'package:fsm2_viewer/src/providers/current_page.dart';
import 'package:fsm2_viewer/src/providers/log_provider.dart';

class PageButtons extends ConsumerWidget {
  final List<SvgFile> pages;
  PageButtons(this.pages);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    /// watch the currentPageProvider so we are rebuilt when the page
    /// no changes.
    int currentPage = watch(currentPageProvider).currentPage;
    log('building PageButons currentPage: $currentPage');
    if (pages.length == 0) {
      return Container(width: 0, height: 0);
    }

    currentPage = min(currentPage, pages.length - 1);

    var buttons = <Widget>[];
    for (var pageNo = 0; pageNo < pages.length; pageNo++) {
      buttons.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
          child: RaisedButton(
              color: (pageNo == currentPage ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
              onPressed: () {
                context.read(logProvider).log = 'onpressed';
                /// User click the page button so update the current page.
                context.read(currentPageProvider).currentPage = pageNo;
                context.read(logProvider).log = 'changed to page $pageNo';
              },
              child: Text('${pageNo + 1}'))));
    }
    return Row(children: buttons);
  }
}
```

You can see in the above build method I call watch:

```dart
 int currentPage = watch(currentPageProvider).currentPage;
```

Then in the onPressed for a Raised button I update the currentPage:

```dart
              onPressed: () {
                /// User click the page button so update the current page.
                context.read(currentPageProvider).currentPage = pageNo;
                context.read(logProvider).log = 'onpressed';                
                context.read(logProvider).log = 'changed to page $pageNo';
```

In my logs I see:

```
main:ALL> onpressed
main:ALL> currentPage set to 1
main:ALL> changed to page 1
```

The logs tell me that the onPressed method is being called and that I'm updating the currentPageProvider.

However the PageButtons's builder is not being called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "set to 1".  What was it before that line?  The state has to *change* to get a notify.

Comment: This is just a hunch but I'm not sure that watching the value of your getter will yield the same behavior as watching the state directly.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz It renders multiple buttons and I've tested changing it to different values.

Comment: @AlexHartford If I change the line to use state I get a warning:  int currentPage = watch(currentPageProvider).state;  The member 'state' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart'.

Comment: @BrettSutton You need to do this instead: currentPage = watch(currentPageProvider.state);

Comment: As Homer once said: Doh. thanks that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:math' hide log;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:fsm2/fsm2.dart' hide State;
import 'package:fsm2_viewer/src/providers/current_page.dart';
import 'package:fsm2_viewer/src/providers/log_provider.dart';

class PageButtons extends ConsumerWidget {
  final List<SvgFile> pages;
  PageButtons(this.pages);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    /// watch the currentPageProvider so we are rebuilt when the page
    /// no changes.
    int currentPage = watch(currentPageProvider.state);
    log('building PageButons currentPage: $currentPage');
    if (pages.length == 0) {
      return Container(width: 0, height: 0);
    }

    currentPage = min(currentPage, pages.length - 1);

    var buttons = <Widget>[];
    for (var pageNo = 0; pageNo < pages.length; pageNo++) {
      buttons.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, left: 5),
          child: RaisedButton(
              color: (pageNo == currentPage ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
              onPressed: () {
                context.read(logProvider).log = 'onpressed';
                /// User click the page button so update the current page.
                context.read(currentPageProvider).currentPage = pageNo;
                context.read(logProvider).log = 'changed to page $pageNo';
              },
              child: Text('${pageNo + 1}'))));
    }
    return Row(children: buttons);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: he simply left out the state keyword

int currentPage = watch(currentPageProvider.state); // with this, you are now watching the stateNotifierProvider's state and not the provider itself